# What string date format will JavaScript's parse recognize?

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I know when constructing a `Date` object in JavaScript with a `dateString` parameter, the string must be something that `parse()` can recognize.

What date format can `parse` recognize?

For example:

```
var postDate = new Date("2011-03-08T23:52:38");
```

works in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but fails on an iPhone (returns Jan 1, 1970).

I cannot find any formal documentation on the `.parse()` method, or the constructor, about what the parameter should be.

The format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss` doesn't work. What *is* the allowed format string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [**MDC documentation of `Date.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) states *(quoting)* :

> It accepts the **IETF standard** *([RFC
> 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) Section 5.2.14 and elsewhere)*
> date syntax: 
> `"Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT"`.

---

**OP Edit:**

.NET syntax to create this datetime string:

```
/*
 * r (RFC1123Pattern)
 *      ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
 *      Mon, 15 Jun 2009 20:45:30 GMT
 */
dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //"r" = RFC1123Pattern
```

> **Edit:** The `r` (RFC1123 pattern) always appends "GMT", even though the time isn't GMT (it's local). You need to call `.ToUniversalTime()` first, in order to have the time *actually* be GMT.

Answer (score 1):

Using the format that is produced by Date's toJSON method will work. This is the same as the toISOString method.

The date format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Note: The time zone is always UTC as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toJSON());
console.log(d.toJSON() === d.toISOString());
console.log(Date.parse(d.toJSON()) === Date.parse(d.toISOString()));
```

You may find that the date shown isn't the same as on your clock; remember the time zone is UTC.

References:

[Date.prototype.toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)

[Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)