# In JavaScript, How to Convert a date time value from one format to the other?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

Please look at the format of these date time values:

```
var from = "2012-01-13 T11:00:00";
var to = "13 Jan 2012 11:00am";
```

In the above example, how to write a javascript function which converts a value in "from" format to a value in "to" format, both are datetime values in text obvioulsy.

```
var to = convertDateTime(from);
function convertDateTime(from)
{
// how to implement this?
}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Comment: Hope this post will be helpful for you .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758999/converting-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

look at this article : 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

you must convert your string object into date type and then retransform it to string using date format

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) that will handle this for you.

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. When working with dates, you can run into several browser inconsistencies.

Comment: This looks like a great library with a lot of useful functionality, but is probably overkill for most sites. `Date` doesn't suffer from cross-browser differences. AFAIK it's well implemented across all major browsers.

Comment: @wheresrhys The recognized date formats a Date object can be initialized from differs a lot among browsers normally supported nowadays.

Comment: I never knew that. Do you know of any sources documenting this? The closest I've found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418631/what-string-date-format-will-javascripts-parse-recognize, but it doesn't come close to saying which formats work where.

Comment: @wheresrhys Unfortunately not. It would be great to have a table of browsers / supported date formats.