# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object?

Tags: javascript, date

How to convert a date in format `23/10/2015` into a
JavaScript Date format:

```
Fri Oct 23 2015 15:24:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: You have to take it apart as the day and month can switch place.
What have you tried?

Comment: i used the split method and separated it as date, month , year

Comment: ummm, unclear. By "normal date" what do you mean, a string? And by "javascript Date format" what do you mean, a string like you posted or an actual JavaScript Date object???

Comment: yes i want too change a normal date into a javascript date object

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

### MM/DD/YYYY format

If you have the `MM/DD/YYYY` format which is **default for JavaScript**, you can simply pass your string to **`Date(string)`** constructor. It will parse it for you.

```js
var dateString = "10/23/2015"; // Oct 23

var dateObject = new Date(dateString);

document.body.innerHTML = dateObject.toString();
```

### DD/MM/YYYY format - manually

If you work with this format, then you can split the date in order to get day, month and year separately and then use it in another constructor - `Date(year, month, day)`:

```js
var dateString = "23/10/2015"; // Oct 23

var dateParts = dateString.split("/");

// month is 0-based, that's why we need dataParts[1] - 1
var dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]); 

document.body.innerHTML = dateObject.toString();
```

For more information, you can read article about `Date` at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Constructor).

### DD/MM/YYYY - using `moment.js` library

Alternatively, you can use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com) library, which is probably the most popular library to parse and operate with date and time in JavaScript:

```js
var dateString = "23/10/2015"; // Oct 23

var dateMomentObject = moment(dateString, "DD/MM/YYYY"); // 1st argument - string, 2nd argument - format
var dateObject = dateMomentObject.toDate(); // convert moment.js object to Date object

document.body.innerHTML = dateObject.toString();
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In all three examples `dateObject` variable contains an object of type [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which represents a moment in time and can be further converted to any string format.

Comment: you should pass the correct type (number) to the constructor. var dateObject: Date = new Date(+dateParts[2], +dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]);

Comment: This one is giving Fri Oct 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST), And if we need "23 Oct 2015" only not complete string

Comment: There's only *one* country in the whole world using MM/DD/YYYY and what do they set as the default JavaScript format? So annoying.

Comment: you can change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy and vice versa, using regex, with something like this:

const originalDate = '23/07/2020';

const newDate = originalDate.replace(/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/g,'$2/$1/$3');
// newDate = '07/23/2020';

Comment: You can no longer depend on JavaScript parsing MM/DD/YYYY natively, due to changes in the underlying ECMAScript spec. The formats a JavaScript engine will parse are implementation-dependent, with the only ones in the ECMAScript standard being the IETF standard and a form of ISO 8601 (see [What string date format will javascript's parse recognize?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5418631/215552))

Comment: For me, This is not viable as for production I had to parse 1000+ dates for some orders with further processing. Still looking for other solutions but if your data set is small you can use this snippet. 
`var dateString = "23/10/2015";
const correctDateString = new Date(dateString.split('/').reverse().join('/')).toString() \\ 'Fri Oct 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'`

Comment: Why no1 recommends doing this like new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-UK') ?

Answer (score 13):

Here's one I prepared earlier...

```
  convertToDate(dateString) {
      //  Convert a "dd/MM/yyyy" string into a Date object
      let d = dateString.split("/");
      let dat = new Date(d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0]);
      return dat;     
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Parsing a string to create another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser is not an efficient strategy, particularly when neither string is in a format supported by ECMA-262.

A more efficient strategy is to parse the string once and give the parts directly to the constructor, avoiding the second parse, e.g.

```js
const parseDMY = s => {
  let [d, m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(y, m-1, d);
};

console.log(parseDMY('23/10/2015').toString());
```

[*Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) only supports the formats produced by:

1. [*Date.protoype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring)
2. [*Date.protoype.toISOString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring)
3. [*Date.protoype.toUTCString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring)

Parsing of any other format (including m/d/y) is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateString = "23/10/2015"; // Oct 23
var newData = dateString.replace(/(\d+[/])(\d+[/])/, '$2$1');
var data = new Date(newData);

document.body.innerHTML = date.toString();ere
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

While most responses were tied to splitting strings or using native date methods, the two closely-related ones using RegEx (i.e., answer by [drgol] and comment by [Tomás Hugo Almeida]) are both instructive about the use of capturing groups. Their succinctness also helps illustrate the value of capturing and [distinguishing that from matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200514/regular-expression-matching-vs-capturing) - two related concepts that can confuse new RegEx users. This code block consolidates their 2 answers but see originals above: `const origDate = '23/07/2020'; const newDate = origDate.replace(/(\d+[/])(\d+[/])/, '$2$1'); // newDate = '07/23/2020';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to transform a date string with a time of day to a date object.  For example to convert "20/10/2020 18:11:25" ("DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS" format) to a date object

```
    function newUYDate(pDate) {
      let dd = pDate.split("/")[0].padStart(2, "0");
      let mm = pDate.split("/")[1].padStart(2, "0");
      let yyyy = pDate.split("/")[2].split(" ")[0];
      let hh = pDate.split("/")[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0].padStart(2, "0");
      let mi = pDate.split("/")[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[1].padStart(2, "0");
      let secs = pDate.split("/")[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[2].padStart(2, "0");
    
      mm = (parseInt(mm) - 1).toString(); // January is 0
    
      return new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mi, secs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the default JS date formatting didn't work.

So I used `toLocaleString` with `options`

```
const event = new Date();
const options = { dateStyle: 'short' };
const date = event.toLocaleString('en', options);
```

to get: DD/MM/YYYY format

See docs for more formatting options: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. They're trying to convert a string into a date.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this short function

```
// dateString: "15/06/2021"
```

```js
const stringToDate = (dateString) => {
  const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/');
  return new Date([month, day, year].join('/'));
};

document.body.innerHTML = stringToDate("15/06/2021").toString();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, what this does is convert a dd/mm/yyyy into a mm/dd/yyyy string, instead of just returning the Date object. Also, this is the same as in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is simpler es6 way to do it, I think that you didn't see the return new Date which acaxtly the answer

Comment: Because `new Date(year, month-1, day)` is too easy? :-)

Answer (score -4):

```
var date = new Date("enter your  date");//2018-01-17 14:58:29.013
```

Just one line is enough no need to do any kind of `split`, `join`, etc.:

```
$scope.ssdate=date.toLocaleDateString();//  mm/dd/yyyy format
```

Comment: The OP asked for DD/MM/YYYY format which is not supported by Date in javascript

Comment: He is right, you can get desired Indian Format by `date.toLocaleString("indian");` or `date.toLocaleDateString("indian");`

Comment: The Op is asking for "string to date", not "date to string".

Answer (score -4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>

dateString = "23/10/2015";    //23 Oct 2015

d = dateString.split("/");

x = d[1] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[2];    //"10/23/2015"
y = d[2] + "/" + d[1] + "/" + d[0];    //"2015/10/23"

alert(
new Date(x) + "\n\n" +
new Date(y) + "\n\n" +
new Date(dateString) + "\n" +
"");

</script>
```