# How to add jquery variable data in php statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am getting stuck on this problem. i want to do using jquery

```
window.newdatevalue = '<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>';// this date is dynamic

var newdate = window.newdatevalue;

console.log(newdate); // when i print this it give me right result -2017-02-06 

var finaldate = "<?php echo date('d/M/y',strtotime('"+newdate+"'))?>";

console.log(finaldate); // but when i print this it give me wrong result 01/Jan/70
```

Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong

Comment: try change finaldate format to "Y-m-d" [  echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('"+newdate+"')) ]

Comment: i tried it but its not working @SarangaR

Comment: PHP executes on the server, then the server sends the page to the browser, and javascript runs. You can't just inject a javascript variable in PHP, it's too late

Comment: for change date format see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object

Comment: I think, you are misunderstanding some principle of server side programming any way I think you hope following answer [ echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));  ] or [ echo date('d/m/Y'); ]

Answer (score 0):

Can try this. It might help you.

```
window.newdatevalue = '<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))); ?>'

console.log(window.newdatevalue);
```

Comment: where is $originalDate;

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: i have  different date in different day. So i want to place variable in strtotime

Comment: what you mean in above... please specify more clearly