# German date validation with date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a string with a german date (31.01.2019, DD.MM.YYYY).
Now I need to check if the date is valid with date-fns.

```
dateFns.isValid(new Date('19.11.2019'), 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

This is not working. I always get a false feedback from date-fns. 
I think date-fns is expecting another date format.

How can I validate the string with the german date format?

Comment: If you pass a string to `new Date` then it has to be in the ISO format, any other format either results in an invalid date or in an unpredictable result. And `19.11.2019` is not a valid string to create a Date.

Comment: You can split it at every dot `.` and then use the `Date` constructor like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299764

Answer (score 4):

You can use`isValid` and `parse` functions of the date-fns library  :

```
import { isValid, parse } from 'date-fns';

// parse the string to a Date
const date = parse('31.08.2012', 'dd.MM.yyyy', new Date());

// then check the validity of that date
isValid(date)
```

Check the documentation for more details on these functions : https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started

Comment: could you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67760399/how-to-replicate-a-function-using-date-fns

Answer (score 0):

From the date-fns the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/isValid) :

> Returns false if argument is Invalid Date and true otherwise. Invalid
>   Date is a Date, whose time value is NaN.

Since `new Date('19.11.2019')` gives already an `Invalid Date` (since it is not ISO formatted) therefore you get `false`.

If you want to use german format you should [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object/33299764#33299764) your date format to the ISO one.

Comment: Thanks. date-fns supports only the format yyyy-mm-dd for validation? is this correct?

Comment: @HansPeter before version 2.x (which is still alpha), the `isValid` function only accepts a `Date` object as input, and checks if that `Date` object holds a valid date information. It does not do any validation of the format, only if it holds a valid date. And a javascript `Date` object does not hold any format, it just holds a representation of a date. And `new Date` only accepts dates in the ISO format.