# How to replicate a function using date-fns

Tags: javascript

I am using momentjs. Using it i created this function:

```js
const convertToLocalTime = (userHour) => {
  return userHour + moment().set("hours", userHour).utcOffset() / 60;
}

console.log(convertToLocalTime(4))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Now i want to replicate this function using `date-fns` library, but i don't figure out how to do this, not being able to find the alternative methods in date-fns. 
 How, using date-fns to replicate the function above that use momentjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `date-fns`, but you don't need any library for this.

Here's that same logic using JavaScript's built-in `Date` object:

```js
const convertToLocalTime = (userHour) => {
    const dt = new Date();
    dt.setHours(userHour);
    return userHour - dt.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
};

console.log(convertToLocalTime(4));
```

Note that Moment's `utcOffset` and `Date`'s `getTimezoneOffset` have their sign reversed.

There's an alternative approach you might use, since JavaScript's `Date` object has both local and UTC date/time funtions:

```js
const convertToLocalTime = (userHour) => {
    const dt = new Date();
    dt.setUTCHours(userHour); // Set the hours using the UTC function
    return dt.getHours();     // Get the hours using the local time function
};

console.log(convertToLocalTime(4));
```