# Convert Date string to Object with current timezone format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code to add a reminder to a calendar

```
function addCalendarEvent(eventDate, eventTitle){
  let dateObj = new Date(eventDate);
  let calendarId = "me@gmail.com";
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  let event = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, dateObj)
  event.addEmailReminder(420)

}
```

The `eventDate` is passed into the function as a `string` in the format `dd/MM/YYYY` but the output from `let dateObj = new Date(eventDate);` is in american format. ie. `02/10/2020` comes out as `Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`. Any help correcting this would be great. Dates give me an absolute headache

Comment: Please indicate the format of `eventDate` when it is passed and your expected output. Will `eventDate` always be in the same format/timezone?

Comment: what s the output you are expecting for `dateObj`

Comment: Hi. Just realised it was wrong in the question. Its passed in as `dd/MM/YYYY` so I would expect say `02/10/2020` to come out as `Mon Oct 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)` (might not be a monday).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 2):

In the end I decided that just working with date objects from the off would be easiest

Comment: Great decision!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `date` object of the string in the format `dd/MM/YYYY`

```
function ddmmyyyytFormatterWithTime(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('/');
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(dateDiv[0]);
  date.setMonth(--dateDiv[1]); // -- since it starts from 0
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[2]--);

  return date;
};

function ddmmyyyytFormatter(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('/');
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // to reset time
  date.setDate(dateDiv[0]);
  date.setMonth(--dateDiv[1]); // -- since it starts from 0
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[2]); 

  return date;
};

var date = ddmmyyyytFormatter("10/02/2020");
var dateWithTime = ddmmyyyytFormatterWithTime("10/02/2020");
```