# converting dates into different format gives invalid date error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a date which is like this `"19/05/2020"`. I am trying to convert it into `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format using pipe. So the date should be look like `"2020-05-19"`.

```
this._datePipe.transform("19/05/2020", 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

It is giving me an error saying `Unable to convert "19/04/2020" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe`

Also tried converting the string to date but again invalid date message is getting display.

Is there any way so that we can convert this date that is  "19/05/2020" to a valid one so that we can perform datepipe on it.

Comment: Have you tried converting the string into a datetime object

Comment: Why a date pipe ? Use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) instead `moment("19/05/2020", 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: @marcusshep yes tried converting the date to datetime object but getting  invalid date. If the date which I have used is in format "yyyy-MM-dd" then new Date() is working fine but if I am providing it in some another format getting invalid date

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle We dont want to use third party library.

Comment: You need a valid date object in order to use date transformations. The string you have is not a valid date string so you either have to provide a valid date string that you can use, or simply use string manipulation to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to convert your date having a supported formatted string :

For example, "2011-10-10" (date-only form), "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date-time form), or "2011-10-10T14:48:00.000+09:00" (date-time form with milliseconds and time zone) can be passed and will be parsed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

This is valid for `Date.parse()` or `new Date()`.

So you'll need to parse your string with another method.

This may helps you :

[How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object)