# Check if date is bigger then other date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: javascript, date

I have two dates .

```
var dateOne = "24/04/1995"
var dateTwo = "24/04/1998"
```

How can i check if one date is bigger than the other?

I tried this :

```
function myFunction() {
  
    var d1 = Date.parse(dateOne);
    var d2 = Date.parse(dateTwo);
    if (d1 < d2) {
    alert ("Error! Date did not Match");
     }
}
```

but its not working =(

there is a method for this dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Relying on `Date.parse` for dd/MM/yyyy format is a bad idea. Read [this fully](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 2):

Relying on the docs around [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

You can simply cast to a Number and compare:

```
const isDateOneBigger = +dateOne > +dateTwo;
```

However in your case your Dates are invalid. You can check this by logging out `d1` which will result in `NaN`. If you take a look at [How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object) you'll see how you can convert your strings into correct dates.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I hadn't realised that but you're very much correct!

Comment: *(I deleted my earlier comment, sorry didn't realize you'd replied.)* `<` will do that implicitly. The real problem with the OP's code is relying on parsing that date format.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep I've just worked that out. I'm going to update my answer to accommodate that

Comment: This is an **often** repeated duplicate, there's really no need for answers here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

use the `getTime()` as so

```
function myFunction() {
  
    var d1 = new Date(dateOne);
    var d2 = new Date(dateTwo);
    if (d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()) {
    alert ("Error! Date did not Match");
     }
}
```

the `getTime()` method convert the date into milliseconds

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the info i didnt know that actually

Comment: *(I deleted my earlier comment, sorry didn't realize you'd replied.)* `<` will do that implicitly. The real problem with the OP's code is relying on parsing that date format.

Comment: This is just a different formulation of the OP code with the same error: using the built–in parser for an unsupported format (or using the built–in parser at all).