# I am converting Json date into date object but due to another timezone server time getting change. I want to remain the date and time zone same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

```
this.convertJSON_DateTimeTo_datetimeObj = function (jsonDate) {
            var date_dd_MM_yyyy = $filter('date')(jsonDate.slice(6, -2), 'medium');
            //var dt = new Date(date_dd_MM_yyyy).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" });
            //var dt = new Date(date_dd_MM_yyyy.split("/").reverse().join("/"));
            return date_dd_MM_yyyy;
        },
```

Input Parameter jsonDate = "/Date(1629810881857)/"

In the above code, I want to convert JSON DateTime into DateTime Object where the output timezone is "Asia/Kolkata". code in the comment is that which is already tried by me. It's very helpful for me if any body help me Thanks

Comment: Can you please include (part) of your `jsonDate`. We can't magically guess what it looks like. Check out [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: based on the name of the variables I am guessing the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format.  If yes, you need to convert to mm/dd/yyyy format to convert it to javscript Date object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299764/4018180

Comment: Input Parameter jsonDate = "/Date(1629810881857)/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with this. First, the server isn't sending any timezone information in the `/Date(1629810881857)/` string. This means you can't safely convert it to Asia/Kolkata timezone because you don't know what you're converting it *from*. You need to get the server to send that information in its response.

Once you solve that, you need to parse the date string into a JavaScript `Date` properly. [Here's the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/4028303). The `$filter` service shouldn't be needed here.

Lastly, it's best practice to let JavaScript dates convert to the end user's locale as defined in their browser/OS rather than forcing it to display in a particular timezone such as Asia/Kolkata. However, if you want to always display a particular timezone no matter where the user is located, [here is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/4028303) explaining how that works.

Comment: The term "locale" has been somewhat compromised by its use in ECMA-402 as a synonym for "language" (the *locale* parameter is a BCP-47 language tag) rather than location. So while the common meaning of locale should indicate timezone, in the context of ECMA-402 (i.e. *Intl.DateTimeFormat* and *toLocaleString*) it doesn't. Also, the location in OS settings isn't necessarily where the user is actually located, it's typically just the place that the OS gets its offset data from. :-)